# How can I force git to use mergetool on all changes?

Tags: git, merge

I have a project in c on my computer that has his own repo and branches in git. The I had to integrate that on another device and we made some changes there too. Then these changed files were sent back to me via email as an achive.

Now I want to make a merge between my repo and the new files picking each line that I want changed and which one shouldn't be changed, but git shows me no merge conflicts and simply applies the new changes over the old files.

Comment: Did the archive get sent to you as a zipped git repository? If not, just use the mergetool directly to merge folders rather than trying to involve git

Comment: @Collin Thanks. You could post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved use mergetool on the folders. I didn't knew that.